# Ajuda pra converter SQL em LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Quero converter o código `select` para uma consulta `LINQ`

```
SELECT bpac.cmp FROM bpac
union
SELECT bpai.cmp FROM bpai
group by cmp
order by cmp desc
```

Estou tentando pegar a primeira tabela e já estou tendo erro:

```
List<string> listaBpac = modelOff.bpacs.Where(p => p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge)
                                    .Select(p => new { p.cmp })
                                    .ToList();
```

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list "anonimous type: string cmp"' to 'system.collections.generic.list "anonimous type: string"'

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

List listaBpac = modelOff.bpacs.Where(p => p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge)
                                    .Select(p => p.cmp)
                                    .ToList();